# How to find the total of an 2d array?

Tags: java

Have to input numbers of students & subjects. (Using random marks) I want to ***print*** the **total marks of students** & the **total marks of subjects.** Here is the code given below.

```
import java.util.*;
class Example{
    public static void readMarks(int[][] x){
        Random r=new Random();
        for(int i=0; i<x.length; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<x[i].length; j++){
                x[i][j]=r.nextInt(101);
            }
        }
    }
    public static void printMarks(int[][] x){
        for(int i=0; i<x.length; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<x[i].length; j++){
                System.out.print(x[i][j]+"  ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    public static int[] findStudenTot(int[][] x){
        int tot[]=new int[x.length];

        for(int i=0; i<x.length; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j<x[i].length; j++){
                tot[i]+=x[i][j];
            }
        }
        return tot;
    }
    public static int[] findSubjectTot(int[][] x){
        int tot1[]=new int[x.length];

        for(int i=0; i<x.length; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j<x[i].length; j++){
                tot1[i]+=x[i][j];
            }
        }
        return tot1;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Input no of students : ");
        final int N=input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Input no of subject : ");
        final int S=input.nextInt();

        int[][] marks=new int[N][S];
        readMarks(marks);

        int[] stTotal=findStudenTot(marks);
        int[] subTotal=findSubjectTot(marks);

        System.out.println("total is : "+stTotal);
        System.out.println("total is : "+subTotal);

    }
}
```

How to print stTotal , subTotal?

If we assume enter 5 for both inputs this output total is : [I@3d4eac69 ...why?
what are these characters & how can I avoid these?

Comment: So, why are you returning an int array when your method returns a 2D int array? Your error message is telling you exactly what is wrong.

Comment: then what should i return, should i delete that

Comment: `findStudenTot` returns ant `int[][]` but you are expecting ant `int[]`. Change method to `public static int[] findStudenTot(int[][] x)`

Comment: If you want the error to go away, a 2D int array... int[][] as expected. If you want the actual total... it should probably be an int. And your method return should match that.

Comment: then what should I type

Comment: subTotal is equal to stTotal... how should I apply changes to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to print stTotal , subTotal?

Do it as follows:

```
System.out.println("total is : " + Arrays.toString(stTotal));
System.out.println("total is : " + Arrays.toString(subTotal));
```

**[Update]**

Replace the definition of `findSubjectTot` with the following:

```
public static int[] findSubjectTot(int[][] x) {
    int tot[] = new int[x[0].length];

    for (int i = 0; i < x[0].length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < x.length; j++) {
            tot[i] += x[j][i];
        }
    }
    return tot;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But subTotal is equal to stTotal... how should I apply changes to it.

Comment: There is no difference in your `findStudenTot` and `findSubjectTot`. Let me correct them. I will post the corrected methods in a few minutes.

Comment: I have posted the update. I hope, it meets your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

i think the issue lies in findStudentTot Method, you seem to have return type of 2D array but is returning a 1D array so this should solve it

```
public static int[] findStudenTot(int[][] x){
    int tot[]=new int[x.length];

    for(int i=0; i<x.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j<x[i].length; j++){
            tot[i]+=x[i][j];
        }
    }
    return tot;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not certain what you want but try this.  Change `int[][]` to `int[]` as the return type.

```
  public static int[] findStudenTot(int[][] x){
        int tot[]=new int[x.length];
    // rest of code here.
```